# Laravel - Can't handle RequestException (Guzzle + MailChimp)

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, mailchimp, guzzle

I'm trying to handle a 404 request exception. It's the first time I'm using Guzzle so I'm unable to handle the exception without the error promps first, I need to check the error code because on the mailchimp API its the error code that gives us the informations we need.

Instead i'm getting this in response - http://prntscr.com/db9ari

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Newsletter;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{


    public function api()
    {

        $mailchimp = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/']);

        try {
            $checkEmail = $mailchimp->request('GET', 'lists/LIST-ID/members/' . md5('EMAIL), [ 'headers' => [ 'Authorization' => 'apikey ' . config('globals.mailchimp_key') ]]);
        }

        catch( RequestException $exception ) {

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() === 404)
            {
                return 'STRING THAT I WANT TO RETURN IN CASE OF ERROR';
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try usign something like this:

```
try {
    $checkEmail = $mailchimp->request('GET', 'lists/LIST-ID/members/' . md5('EMAIL), [ 'headers' => [ 'Authorization' => 'apikey ' . config('globals.mailchimp_key') ]]);
}catch( \Exception $e ) {
    if ($e instanceof GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException){
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() === 404)
        {   
            return 'STRING THAT I WANT TO RETURN IN CASE OF ERROR';
        }
    }else{
        // do anything else here
    }
}
```

Comment: That kind of works! I got this (http://prntscr.com/db9m77), how can I use "#code" ?

Comment: try $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html):

> A `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` is thrown for 400 level errors if the `http_errors` request option is set to true

You can solve this in one of two ways:

- Setting the `http_errors` value to `false` when instantiating your client. For your code this woud look like so: `$mailchimp = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/', 'http_errors' => false]);`
- Wrap your call in a try/catch and catch the `ClientException`.

Guzzle will also throw a `ServerException` for any 500 level errors, which you can deal with in the same way